# RecyclerView Not showing data from Json array

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit, retrofit2, recyclerview-layout

Whenever i try to add data to recycler view, the recycler view doesn't show any data. I tried debugging the program and I am successfully getting  JSON data using Retrofit into the application(Checked by printing it in Log). But RecyclerView shows no data.Here is my code:

CartActivity.java

```
 public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView listshowrcy;
List<CartDisplay>  cartlist = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(API.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
    String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("Username");
    Call<List<CartDisplay>> call = api.getCartContent(username);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<CartDisplay>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<CartDisplay>> call, Response<List<CartDisplay>> response) {
            List<CartDisplay> cart = response.body();
            for(CartDisplay cartContent : cart){
                cartlist.add(cartContent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<CartDisplay>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    listshowrcy = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.cartList);
    listshowrcy.setHasFixedSize(true);
    CartAdapter cardadapter = new CartAdapter(cartlist,this,username);
    listshowrcy.setAdapter(cardadapter);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    listshowrcy.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);



}
}
```

CartAdapter.java

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.Holderview> {
private List<CartDisplay> cartlist;
private Context context;
private String username;

public CartAdapter(List<CartDisplay> cartlist, Context context,String username) {
    this.cartlist = cartlist;
    this.context = context;
    this.username = username;
}

@Override
public Holderview onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View layout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_item,parent,false);
    return new Holderview(layout);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holderview holder, int position) {
    holder.pname.setText(cartlist.get(position).getP_name());
    holder.pquant.setText(cartlist.get(position).getQuantity());
    holder.price.setText(String.valueOf(cartlist.get(position).getPrice()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cartlist.size();
}

class Holderview extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    TextView pname;
    TextView pquant;
    TextView price;

    Holderview(View itemview){
        super(itemview);
        pname = (TextView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        pquant = (TextView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.product_quant);
        price = (TextView)itemview.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @kdblue's answer, there is another issue with your code. The adapter doesn't know that new data has been added to the underlying list.

You can either use `notifyDataSetChanged`:

```
List<CartDisplay> cart = response.body();
for(CartDisplay cartContent : cart){
    cartlist.add(cartContent);
}
cardadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

Or let the adapter handle new items directly, by adding a method to the adapter like:

```
public void add(CartDisplay cartDisplay) {
  cartlist.add(user);
  notifyItemInserted(cartlist.size());
}
```

And adding the items directly to the adapter:

```
List<CartDisplay> cart = response.body();
for(CartDisplay cartContent : cart){
    cardadapter.add(cartContent);
}
```

Be aware that you will have to change you code structure to apply these strategies.

Comment: If an answer helped you solve your problem, consider marking it as accepted so others users can find it more easily. :)

Answer (score 1):

After you get your response you must notify adapter, that data has changed:

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<CartDisplay>> call, Response<List<CartDisplay>> response) {
        List<CartDisplay> cart = response.body();
        cartList.clear(); // don't forget to clear list, to avoid duplicates
        for(CartDisplay cartContent : cart){
            cartlist.add(cartContent);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Another way: you can create method: `adapter.setData(cardList)`
And there refresh adapter data and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`